# Reliable way to get UTC time online?

Tags: java, c#, http, time, utc

Does anybody know where I can get the current plain-and-simple-no-nonsense UTC time accurately and really quickly? Our system clocks are variable due to a number of factors but we need a guiding light to run one of our applications. I was wondering if there was a free service where I can get the time via HTTP without much overhead (i.e. I prefer not to scrape it off somewhere like Google search's with a lot of other data because the application would be looking it up quite often). Does anyone know a reliable service for this?

Comment: Why don't you just use NTP?

Comment: I need it via HTTP though...

Comment: @Tyress Create a HTTP service which queries an NTP server?

Comment: Is this Java or C#? Your question is off topic anyway.

Comment: Why do you _need_ it via HTTP? NTP is dedicated to that and will work better than any HTTP service...

Comment: @DavidG I would answer but it doesn't matter now! Haha.

Comment: @fge an HTTP request would fit right into the existing code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends how accurate you want to get and how much you trust the source.

Possibilities include:

- http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now
- http://timezonedb.com/api
- http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json

Comment: Thanks for this, but while it worked quickly on my first visit using my browser, it seems to lag on subsequent requests....

Comment: (but otherwise this would be what I need)

Comment: That may be a rate limiter to prevent abuse,  how often will you be querying said api?

Comment: mirror for timeapi.org after it went down http://timeapi.herokuapp.com/utc/now

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on how accurate you want the time to be. If it is to synchronise apps/servers, then using a http request to an external server may not be the best approach as you have to take network latency into account. i.e. the time returned may be in the past if the round trip for the request is slowed down by the network, especially if your going via a proxy. And if the apps are running on different machines, with variable network latency the times will not be synced.

An alternative approach would be to ensure that the machines you are running have there systems clocks all synced. A common solution for this is NTP ([Network Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)), which allows servers to keeps there clocks updated accurately.

Here a resource for [NTP configuration on Linux](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/basic-ntp-config.html), I am sure Google will find you more.